# Can’t cd, ls, chown/mod or rm directory — Unknown error: 211 in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, unix, permissions

Never seen something like this in all my years. This is happening in Mac OS X:

```
$ ls -lO@ea
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root  wheel  -             1B Mar 20 23:10 Music/

$sudo cd Music/
cd:13: unknown error: 211: Music

$sudo ls Music/
ls: unknown error: 211: Music

$sudo chown JD:staff Music/
chown: unknown error: 211: Music
```

Take a look at that `Music` directory. It somehow ended up as `root:wheel` with weird permissions (it used to be `755`, `JD:staff` like everything else in the directory). Even with `sudo` or `su`’d as root, I cannot `chown` it, `chmod` it, cd into, `ls` its contents or even `rm -rf` it. I see no weird ACL or `xattrs`. I’ve tried rebooting the system, repairing disk permissions, yet still I cannot touch or get inside this directory.

It isn’t a problem with my `$PATH` because I can use `cd`, `ls`, `chown` just fine on any other file and other than this one directory the entire system works fine. I do not have physical access to this machine, only SSH.

Comment: You should probably check your disk for the errors. Run Disk Utility or reboot OSX or run in recovery mode and Repair Disk and see if you've any, before you'll do any fixes for it, as it could make it worse.